# ggplot: Export ggsave files to emf using ragg fonts

Tags: r, ggplot2, ragg

I'm struggling to combine the use of the `ragg` font package with `ggsave` to an 'emf' file.
If I try to use something like this below having installed the 'Myriad Pro' font (https://fontsgeek.com/myriad-pro-font?ref=readme) using the `ragg` package:

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme(text = element_text(family = "Myriad Pro")) -> plt

ggsave(plt, filename = "test1.emf")
```

When I then insert the resulting emf file into a word document and then save it as a PDF, the text pixels:

[image]

But when I use exactly this procedure using the default font, then this does not happen:

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) + 
  geom_point()  -> plt

ggsave(plt, filename = "test2.emf")
```

[image]

Any idea on how to solve this? I looked in `ragg` for the right device to use but I am none the wiser I'm afraid.

Many thanks!

Comment: I think there's some confusion here (maybe just my own..). `ragg` is a package for raster devices, but your question is about fonts and vector images, right? So how is `ragg` involved?

Comment: Oh that interesting, this could be the reason for all this confusion. I had switched to `ragg` recently due to the ongoing issues with the `extrafont` package. So is what you are saying that this is impossible with ragg?

Comment: Well, I'm not quite sure what happens when you use `ggsave` with an `emf` extension, i.e. what device gets used. But `ragg` doesn't have vector-based devices. The `ragg` related font support lives in the `systemfonts` package.